# counting movement with livewires

Tags: pygame, livewires

so here is my question. i have an image that i want to continuously move side to side on the screen. and i want to display a count each time it does. ive tried to clean up my code to before i messed it all up. can someone help me with what i need to add in order to display a count of each time the image travels from one side of the screen to the other? I'v added the code.
[my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63ebbed6761aa37c581ec7120e1ab8c4)

Answer (score 0):

```
class moving_image(games.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.right > games.screen.width or self.left < 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
            self.counter += 1
```

Comment: then what though? i change the value in score = games.Text(value = 0, size = 25, color = color.black, x = 5, y = 5) and it will work? what do i set it to?

Comment: i try setting score = games.Text(value = moving_image.counter, size = 25, color = color.black, x = 5, y = 5) but i get the error TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
Exception AttributeError: "'moving_image' object has no attribute '_gone'" in <bound method moving_image.__del__ of <__main__.moving_image object at 0x029B6F30>> ignored